# how to get JSON data from login?

Tags: ios, json, oauth, swift3, alamofire

I am able to fetch data using Oauth in Alamofire for login successfully but how to get JSON data in Another viewController.

```
    func loginAccess(){

        let headers = [
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
        let parameters = [

            "UserName": username_textfield.text! as String,
            "Password": password_textfield.text! as String,
            "grant_type": "password",
                    ]


//        let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.100.5:84/Token")!
        Alamofire.request("http://192.168.100.5:84/Token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {

            case .success(_):
                if response.result.value != nil{

                    let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                    print("...HTTP code: \(statusCode)")

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {

                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
//                        }

                    }
                    if statusCode == 200{
                        self.view.makeToast(message: "Welcome !!")
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainview", sender: self)

                    }else{
                    self.view.makeToast(message: "Username or password invalid")
                    }
                }

                break

            case .failure(_):

                print(response.result.error!)
                break

            }
        }
    }
```

**modal class**

```
class Login{

    var access_token = String()
    var token_type = String()
    var expire_in = String()
    var username = String()
    var masterid = String()
    var name = String()
    var access = String()
    var issued = String()
    var expries = String()

    init(loginJson:JSON){
    self.access_token = loginJson["access_token"].stringValue
        self.token_type = loginJson["token_type"].stringValue
        self.expire_in = loginJson["expires_in"].stringValue
        self.username = loginJson["userName"].stringValue
        self.masterid = loginJson["MasterID"].stringValue
        self.name = loginJson["Name"].stringValue
        self.access = loginJson["Access"].stringValue
        self.issued = loginJson[".issued"].stringValue
        self.expries = loginJson[".expires"].stringValue
    }


}
```

is this able to access JSON data in Another ViewController or we need another function? if this is possible in same function then how
it could be solved?

Comment: search in google..there are lot of eg is there to pass data between viewcontollers

Comment: ya i can pass data between view controllers but my question is JSON data passing from login function to another view controller and i have oauth to login  so i m getting confused can u help this one ?

Comment: @BikeshThakur: search for delegation pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace** this with your code

```
func getlogin(){
       let headers = [
           "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
       ]
       let parameters = [

           "UserName": username_textfield.text! as String,
           "Password": password_textfield.text! as String,
           "grant_type": "password",
           ]


       //        let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.100.5:84/Token")!
       Alamofire.request("http://192.168.100.5:84/Token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

           switch(response.result) {
           case.success(let data):
               print("success",data)
                let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
               if statusCode == 200{
                   self.view.makeToast(message: "Welcome !!")
//                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainview", sender: self)

               }else{
                   self.view.makeToast(message: "Username or password invalid")
               }
               self.myResponse = JSON(data)
               let login = Login(loginJson: self.myResponse)
               DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pass_data", sender: login)                    
                                  })

           case.failure(let error):
               print("Not Success",error)
           }

       }
   }
```

**you can add this also**

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       if segue.identifier == "pass_data" {

           if let eventsVC = segue.destination as? secondViewController,

               let loginData = sender as? Login {

               eventsVC.login_details = loginData

           }

       }

   }
```

> in your second view controller you shuold add variable like this var
>   login_details : Login? to get JSON data

Comment: ya i replaced code but its not passing data can u plz give some suggestion to pass data to secondviewController

Comment: happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value using **closure** .

**Create Method**

```
func loginAccess(callBack: (_ responseObject : [Any]) -> Void) -> Void{
       if let JSON = response.result.value {
                            callBack(JSON as Any) // here data passed
                      }
                    }
                    if statusCode == 200{
                        self.view.makeToast(message: "Welcome !!")
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainview", sender: self)

                    }else{
                    self.view.makeToast(message: "Username or password invalid")
                            callBack([:] as Any)

                    }
        }
```

**Calling method**

```
self.loginAccess { (responseObject) in
            print(responseObject) // this is your data
            //create your model here

        }
```

Comment: it saying "tuple element cannot have two labels" and "single argument function types require parentheses" in this line  (callBack: (_ responseObject : [Any] -> Void)) -> Void ,,, please explain this ??

Comment: i have edited my code there is some changes and @escaping itself proviede while having this code callBack(JSON as Any)

Comment: any issue there?

Comment: no any errors is it ok for having that @espace .and  how can i pass modules to another view controller can u help me please ??

Comment: where to call this function self.loginAccess { (responseObject) in
            print(responseObject) // this is your data
            //create your model here

        } having error on this line ??

Comment: loginAccess where you are called ? and did you pushed Another viewController ?

Comment: self.loginAccess { (responseObject) in
                    print(responseObject) // this is your data
                    //create your model here
                    
                } i called this function in action of button and the access_token data is changing in per second

Comment: i called that calling function in this @IBAction func Lgin(_ sender: Any) {
        self.loginAccess { (responseObject) in
            print(responseObject) // this is your data
            //create your model here
            
        }
    } and my access_token data is changing in per second and other data are same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147603/discussion-between-bikesh-thakur-and-kkrocks).

Comment: can you exlpani me how to call model in this function self.loginAccess { (responseObject) in
            print(responseObject) // this is your data
            //create your model here

        } i have now no errors in access token i have solved it

Answer (score -1):

How to get data from this login?

```
func onlinecheckin(){
        self.password.resignFirstResponder()
        let password1 = password.text;
       if let user1 = user.text {
                 // To trim the characters to remove the empty space
       let username = user1.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
       let passwordnya = password1!.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
                 //Send user data to server side
           let myUrl = URL(string: "https://link/jgcm/login.php")!
              var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
                 request.httpMethod = "POST"
               let postString = "user=\(username) & password=\(passwordnya)"
               
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
           
                 task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {                data, response, error in
                    
                     print("response online checking =\(String(describing: response))")
                     if error != nil {
                         task.cancel() // To cancel uploading the task.
                         self.AlertMessage("Error. Please press Login button again.");
                         print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                         return
                     }
                   
                     if let datadownload = data {
                         resultlogin = NSString(data: datadownload, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "");
                         print("result of online checking:\(resultlogin)")
                     }
                   
                     DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                      if resultlogin.contains("already") {
                       
                       let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menu")
                       self.present(secondViewController!,animated: true,completion: nil)
                       
                         } else {
                             self.AlertMessage("User atau Password Salah");
                         }
                     })
                 }
                 task.resume()
          }}
```